# Google Closure Compiler ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS - Exclude All function names

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google's Closure Compiler to reduce the size of my Java Script code. Unfortunately the Closure Compiler does also change ALL function names in the Advanced mode without an easy option to change that.

I do need to exclude functions that are defined as properties (e.g. `car.bla = function()` ) completely. This includes the ones that I use and that are not defined at all in the local code, and the ones that I define myself.

I know that there is externs and exports (although I don't fully understand them) but I do not want to have to keep maintaining any extra files beside my code.

I would also be find to exclude any functions (also non-property functions).

After googling for a few hours I've still not found an options for that.

Comment: it should not rename externally reachable methods, so over publishing should help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm for example calling a function server.DoStuff and it's changing it to server.aa
server is not defined in my files locally but is a global variable in the environment in which the code is used.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823811/prevent-google-closure-compiler-from-renaming-settings-objects

Comment: Not really, they talk about extern files and annotiation, though I just look for a way to disable this altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers here;

1. Use `@export` to label a property as "used by external sources", such as an Angular binding.
2. Create an `externs`. These are used when you have code that is compiled separately from your code, but they need to interact. Have a look at how simple [Angular's](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/closure-compiler/master/contrib/externs/angular-1.5.js) externs are.
3. Reduce your compilation level to `WHITESPACE_ONLY`
4. Depending on your setup, you may be able to pass `--property_renaming=ALL_UNQUOTED` and use `foo['bar']` to access `foo.bar`
5. Depending on your setup, you may be able to Pass `--property_renaming=OFF`